# all non-system cmd and powershell commands and scripts return error referencing quicktime- regardless of the content of the command or script

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, error-correction

I'm not sure what caused this, but for the past few weeks every single cmd and powershell command I attempt to run, with the exception of built-in system commands, returns the same error:

`\QuickTime\QTSystem was unexpected at this time.`

I've tried deleting the sole user-made ps1 profile file, and cleared HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console entries that sources I found while looking for a fix seemed to agree would reset both powershell and cmd to system defaults. The issue persists. Again: none of the commands or scripts mention quicktime at all. I have no idea what might have caused this and I'm now out of ideas on how to fix it.

Any suggestions on a fix? Is this issue familiar to anybody out there? I've put several hours into searching for solutions and not a single result has been relevant.

editing to clarify something: I don't believe this issue has anything to do with quicktime. The issue is that an unrelated program is for whatever reason being called on automatically every time a command or script is run. This is why my first troubleshooting attempts involved searching for a profile that I may have somehow set as the default.

Comment: Could it be something in your PROMPT?

Comment: I don't know much about how cmd and powershell work. What exactly do you mean/how would I check?

Comment: Sorry, it can't be related if it's happening in both, so we need to look for something in common. Is QuickTime in your PATH? If yes, try to remove it.

Comment: This WAS the issue. I removed quicktime paths from my environment variables and immediately regained cmd and powershell function. Thanks a lot, this was driving me crazy

Comment: Normally you invite the person who supplied the solution to write the answer, which you then accept by clicking the ✔ sign next to the answer.

Comment: sorry, brand new here. working out how it works

Comment: No problem, I have put up my answer. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell and CMD have almost nothing in common, except that they are
both dependent on basic Windows mechanisms.

The most logical reason for such a general and common problem was
therefore a problem with the PATH.

After verification, the poster found a problematic QuickTime entry.
Removing the entry fixed the problem and restored both PowerShell and CMD
to full function.